# Best_in_place change date format rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

How can I change the display date format of `2017-10-27` to `October 27, 2017` using the best_in_place gem.

```
 Date: <%= best_in_place [@request, message], :date %>
```

When I added `:date.strftime("%B %d, %Y")` returned an error

Comment: what error are you facing?

Comment: @Anand undefined method `strftime' for :date:Symbol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add `display_as: :formatted_date` to the `best_in_place` method invocation. So your helper will look like `<%= best_in_place [@request, message], :date, display_as: :formatted_date %>`.

And in your Request model you should define method:

```
def formatted_date
  self.date.strftime("%B %d, %Y")
end
```

Comment: When I edit the date it reverts back to the previous date how can I maintain the format when edited?

Comment: Take a look at [this section](https://github.com/bernat/best_in_place#date)

I suppose you are using jQuery datepicker, so you need to customize `$.datepicker.setDefaults` too