# Rails Best In Place date initial date format

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery-ui, best-in-place

I'm really new to Rails and I'm using v6.1.4. In my application I'm using I18n localization. At other places for view-only label dates(not using BIP) I use

```
<%=l @client.active_date.to_date %>
```

and it works. However, in Best-In-Place there is a different syntax.

```
<span class="date-container"><%= best_in_place task, :due_date, :as => :date, class: 'hyperlink'  %></span>
```

This causes the dates to be displayed in the yyyy-mm-dd format throughout. I want the dates to be formatted according to the locales currently in my application. I'm using the JQuery datepicker, but it is activated after I click on the date, and the format is changed to what I have set on the jquery setDefaults option.

How do I tackle this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47066970/best-in-place-change-date-format-rails) addresses your question.

You could add a `display_as: :formatted_date` to your method call and define that `formatted_date` method in your model. From there you should be able to format dates as needed.

Comment: This is great, but this only sets the date to a particular format and does not localize. Could you show me how I can use I18n in the controller?

Comment: Hello Pratham, sure. As the `strftime` method accepts a string as its first parameter, you could add a localized string there. For ex: `self.date.strftime(t('global.date_format'))`